# simple query that gets the count of column grouping by them

Tags: sql

I am doing some examples queries

I need to get the below output in white (below submit sql)

the below is my query and in the green the output of query and this is the [relation of tables](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House)

```
 select guest_id, count(nights) , sum(nights) from booking 
inner join guest on guest.id=booking.guest_id
where guest_id in(1185,1270)
group by guest_id,nights
```

[image]

Comment: did you try "group by guest_id"?

Comment: @Amit1011 as it is shown in my query `group by guest_id,nights`

Comment: No, i am saying only "group by guest_id" and not "group by guest_id,nights"

Comment: @Moudiz,Group by guest_id only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRY THIS** Everything is fine with your code just you have to `group by` only `guest_id`, if you add `nights` also in `group by` then `COUNT` & `SUM` will be calculated accordingly by grouping data using both the columns:

```
select guest_id, count(nights) , sum(nights) 
from booking 
inner join guest on guest.id=booking.guest_id
where guest_id in(1185,1270)
group by guest_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try following query

`Select a.guest_id,count(nights),sum(nights)`
   `from booking a inner join guest b on a.guest_id=b.id`
  `where a.guest_id in (1185,1270)`
   `group by a.guest_id`

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT guest_id, 
       Count(nights), 
       Sum(nights) 
FROM   booking 
WHERE  guest_id IN ( 1185, 1270 ) 
GROUP  BY guest_id
```

Comment: Please format as code and also provide an explanation. Code without explanation is not helping.